# GPUImage giving strange outputs on Adreno GPU but working fine on Mali GPU

Tags: android, opengl-es, gpu, textures, gpuimage

I converted blur shader from shader toy to use in Android. By using GPUImage my shader is working absolutely fine on my Oppo device having GPU Mali-G72 MP3 and other devices having Mali GPU. But when I run the code on my Samsung A71 having  GPU Adreno 618 and other devices having same Adreno GPU the output image is pixelated like second image.

[image: Output from Mali GPU]

[image: Output from Adreno GPU]

What can be the issue?

I am using GPUImage this way:

```
   Bitmap bitmap = resizeBitmap(original, 1000, 1000);

    GPUImage gpuImage = new GPUImage(this);


    GPUImageFilter filter = new GPUImageFilter(remap(45, 0, 100, 7, 45), new float[]{bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight()}, 3);

    gpuImage.setImage(bitmap);

    gpuImage.setFilter(filter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue fixed. The reasons it was happening was that in Adreno GPU's changing gamma values were prone to pixelate the image. I was raising gamma of image to 8.0 then after some adjustments I was normalizing gamme to 1.0/8.0. Decreasing the value from 8.0 to 3.7 helped me normalize gamme.